# iphone username password MD5

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having one UITextField label as Password and Username. I have to convert UItextField (input from the keyboard) to MD5 and store it to another UITextfield. Code would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for OpenSSL, which is part of the iOS SDK. It contains a very simple MD5 hashing function called `MD5()` (it's in `<openssl/md5.h>`).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this has been answered but wondered if a complete code example would help others:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

+ (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input 
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```